# GETDATE() but without hours

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I need to call `getdate()` and I need a `datetime` returned, however without the current time, e.g. today it should return the following, no matter what time it is called:

```
2013-09-26 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 14):

For SQL 2008/2012:

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

or other versions:

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: the first option has better performance

Answer (score 8):

Lots of options here:

```
-- all versions:

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, {fn CURDATE()});

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0);

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));

-- 2008+:

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));

-- 2012+:

DECLARE @d DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), MONTH(@d), DAY(@d), 0,0,0,0);
```

You may be tempted to do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 112));
```

Don't. [This is bad news](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime).